# Oracle ODI 11g - Multiple Files of different formats

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

I am using Oracle ODI 11.1.1.7.
I have 6, pipe delimited files. Each file has different number of columns. Number of columns is fixed in each file. So I know the format. I want to load all these files in a single table in database.
I can create ODI process with steps in sequential order and call interfaces created for these files to accomplish the task.
Is there any better way to do this? Like creating only one interface which can work with all these files. Something i can do through a loop?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately as these files have a different structure (number of columns), you will need have a different source datastore for each of them so you will need different interfaces.

If the structure were the same, you could use only one datastore and one interface. You would need to use a variable as the filename in the datastore definition and create a loop in a package that would change the value of the variable and execute the interface loading the file.